# Deserializing a list of JSON objects having object's ID as an object name

Tags: java, json, gson

So I have this interesting Json from the Nest API that I need to parse but am having difficulty. Obviously, I dont have control over the JSON.

```
{
    "uyuyuyuuyieiehuhuhuhenne": {
        "name": "Cabin",
        "country_code": "US",
        "postal_code": "94304",
        "time_zone": "America/Los_Angeles",
        "away": "home",
        "structure_id": "uyuyuyuuyieiehuhuhuhenne"
    },
    "ryryryyryryyryrryyryryyr": {
        "name": "Boulder Home",
        "country_code": "US",
        "postal_code": "80302",
        "time_zone": "America/Denver",
        "away": "away",
        "structure_id": "ryryryyryryyryrryyryryyr"
    }
}
```

The object names are the id's of the object. I have an object called structures that contains a List but Im getting nothing in the conversion of the structure.

Comment: Is there really a comma missing before `"structure_id"`? Java?

Comment: @pirho No, Ill fix. Its an abbreviated JSON and I threw those in just to show the structure_id matches the name and didnt fix the comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a POJO like:

```
@Getter
public class Structure {
    private String name;
    private String country_code;
    private String postal_code;
    private String time_zone;
    private String away;
    private String structure_id;
}
```

you can deserialize this JSON to a `Map` by using Gson `TypeToken` like:

```
Type t = new TypeToken<Map<String, Structure>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, Structure> map = new Gson().fromJson(JSON, t);
```

In other words your JSON is a map of `Structure`s having each `Structure`'s `structure_id` as a key.

Comment: This got me where I needed to go. Thanks.